# How the jasmine call is working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine

In `261 Testing JavaScript with Jasmine` [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/261-testing-javascript-with-jasmine-revised) Rayan calls `jasmine` tests like this

> localhost:3000/jasmine

I don't understand where jasmine action is came up. I've checked `routes.rb` and other files and can't find where the `jasmine` action is defined

How `jasmine` action calls javascript tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The railscast episode you mention uses the [jasminerice gem](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice/), which is a rails engine that provides the '/jasmine' route and controller.

If you poke through the jasminerice source, [this file](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice/blob/master/lib/jasminerice.rb#L8) is where the rails engine is mounted at '/jasmine'. [This file](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice/blob/master/config/routes.rb) provides the routes for the rails engine and [this one](https://github.com/bradphelan/jasminerice/blob/master/app/controllers/jasminerice/spec_controller.rb) is the controller that is called for the main route.